# Меняется цвет изображения категории WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

При загрузке изображения категории товаров происходит изменение цвета фото. От черного к коричневому.

Проверил стили, скачал картинку через инспектор, она стала именно коричневой.

При просмотре картинки через инспектор, она имеет коричневый оттенок [image: картинка через инспектор].

А если я ее скачаю и открою на PC, то она такая, как и должна быть - черная. Ниже прикрепил фото, где совместил два изображения в PS, видно, что они одинаковые [image: совмещенные картинки].

Заметил, что изменяется картинка уже на стадии загрузки в редакторе, приобретает коричневый оттенок [image: изменение цвета в редакторе].

Первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой. Стили проверил.

Answer (score 0):

Исходное изображение скорее всего сохранено не в sRGB цветовом профиле. Когда WordPress создает миниатюры изображений, то присваивает sRGB профиль. Вам нужно открыть исходное изображение, например в Photoshop, далее File -> Save for Web -> Convert to sRGB.
Подробнее о проблемах с изображениями можно почитать [здесь](https://wordpress.com/support/images/troubleshooting-images/)